# get path file from webinf folder in ZUL ZK 3.6

Tags: java, zk, zul

how i can get real path of file.xml from web-inf in ZUL, i try this:

```
org.zkoss.zrss.RssFeed feed;
org.zkoss.zrss.RssBinder binder = new org.zkoss.zrss.RssBinder();

try {
    feed = binder.lookUpFeed(new File("/WEB-INF/lesscoutsBeRss.xml").toURI().toURL().toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.getStackTrace();
}
```

but i have problem ,I think the problem because of the bad good recovery path

```
Failed to load /MainPage/rss_lesscouts.zul

Cause: Null Pointer in Method Invocation
java.lang.NullPointerException: Null Pointer in Method Invocation
    at bsh.Name.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHPrimarySuffix.doSuffix(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHVariableDeclarator.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.BSHTypedVariableDeclaration.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source)
    at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source)

...
```

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use this, in order to retrieve the full path of WEB-INF folder in a ZK project:

```
Sessions.getCurrent().getWebApp().getRealPath("")+"/WEB-INF/"
```

Hope this helps you.